# Using dropbox Chooser drop-in to retrieve a non-expiring link to files

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I would like to use the Chooser drop-in to select a file from dropbox and then synchronize my app with that file occasionally in the background.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js

A scenario would be:

1. List item
2. User selects file.
3. File uploads to my app.
4. User returns to my app a few days later after modifying the file in dropbox.
5. My app should synchronize and pull down that particular file (without again displaying the Chooser drop-in).

The problem is that the Chooser provides an expiring link to the file:

> "direct" is an expiring link to download the contents of the file

I can use the Core API exclusively which would work, however I would have to build my own UI to browse the user's dropbox directory. Ideally, I'd prefer to not introduce the world to another file browser; Dropbox has a file browser - and people are familiar with it. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get a preview link and convert it. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/53/programmatically-download-content-from-share-links.